# CSS hierarchy for class and tag

Tags: css, overriding

This is a very basic question. I don't understand why version 1 of the code doesn't do the same as if I'd add everything simply to the .container class.

Thank you very much!

```
.container {
display: flex;
background-color: #FF5722;

}

.container div{
margin: 10px 10px;
padding: 10px;
}

/* why isn't this the same */
.container {
display: flex;
background-color: #FF5722;
margin: 10px 10px;
padding: 10px;
}

<div class="container">
<div class="box-1">...</div>
<div class="box-2">...</div>
<div class="box-3">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem and your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first version you are adding margin and padding to the divs inside your container, not the container itself. In the second version your margin and padding are applied to the container. It’s as simple as that. Styles applied to a parent element (in this case the container) are not automatically applied to the children within, you must set them independently.

When you state `.container div { ... }` you are targeting each `div` inside `container`, not `container` itself.

Comment: Does that mean .container div and div .container are the same thing? Like they would always target the divs inside the container?

Comment: No. `.container div` targets each `div` inside `container`. Meanwhile, `div .container` targets any element with the class `container` inside any `div`. However if you remove the space and say `div.container`, now you’re targeting any `div` with the class `container`.